# How can i apply a conditional formatting rule to all rows except first row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

My problem is about programming in excel (create a formula for conditional formatting rule).

If i use the following formula in my format condition formula:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())>1
```

And apply on all rows *include first* row with following range in `Apply to` field:

```
$A:$F
```

**Result:** It works well.

---

But i want apply it to all rows **except first row**. So i changed it to:

```
=AND(INDIRECT("A"&ROW())>1;ROW()>1)
```

**Result:** Now it did not work on any row.

---

What is my mistake in the above formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first your question is confusing. You can "apply a conditional formatting rule to all rows except first row" by applying it not to `$A:$F` but to `$A$2:$F$1048576`.

But I suspect you want apply it to all rows in columns `$A:$F` but it shall then exclude row 1 while testing conditions.

If so your problem is the volatile behavior of `INDIRECT`. But `INDIRECT` is not needed here. Your first condition can also be written as:

```
=($A1>1)
```

This is because even conditional formatting will respect difference between fixed and variable cell references by using `$` or omitting `$`. So this formula applied to `$A:$F` will check whether `$A1>1` in first row, `$A2>1`in second row, `$A3>1`in third row and so on. This is because the column `$A` is fixed using `$` and so is absolute reference to column `A` but the row number `1` is not fixed and so is a relative reference to the actual row..

Applied to `$A:$F`

[image]

this will have the same behavior as your `INDIRECT` formula, which is: Do Format current row if value of first cell in this row is greater than 1:

[image]

Then to exclude the first row is possible using:

```
=AND($A1>1,ROW()>1)
```

---

One of the disadvantages while using relative cell references in conditional formatting is that they must be changed if the range on which it is applied changes. For example in this case if someone inserts a row above row 1.

But even then `INDIRECT` is not necessary. Then we can use `INDEX` - `MATCH`:

```
=(INDEX($A:$A,ROW())>1)
```

and

```
=AND(INDEX($A:$A,ROW())>1,ROW()>1)
```

Comment: I wrote in the question that my first formula (`=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())>1`) works very well without any problem it works base `$A1` value, `$A2` value, `$A3` value and.... But your suggestion (`$A1>1`) has totally different result and this is not my problem! My problem is adding a condition to the formula to except the first row. I used my final formula (`=AND(INDIRECT("A"&ROW())>1;ROW()>1)`) in a cell and it works well too! But it dose not work in condition formula in conditional formatting rule.

Comment: The formula `=($A1>1)` will have absolute identically result like `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())>1` if applied as conditional formatting to `$A:$F`. What different result should it have? As mentioned in my answer the problem using `INDIRECT` is with its volatile behavior.

Comment: Your rule `=$A1>1` means:  Do format current row if value of `$A1` (**first cell in first row**) is greater than `1`. But `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())>1` means: Do Format current row if value of the **first cell in the current row** is greater than `1`. So for example if i use `=$A1>1` and `$A1` cell value equal `2` then all rows will be format with this rule! and it's completely different with my target.

Comment: Your guess is simply not true. Have you even tried it? The formula `=($A1>1)` applied to `$A:$F` will check whether `$A1>1` in first row, `$A2>1` in second row, `$A3>1` in third row and so on.

Comment: Ouu... I surprised! Because i tested it when you wrote this answer in my excel file and all rows formatted but it seams my test has a bug because i tested it now and it works nice! I'm sorry and thank you for your answer. I gave you +1 for your follow-up this issue to solve the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Using `=($A1>1)` you must be careful on which range you are applying this. Appied to `$A:$F` it works. But applied to `$A$2:$F$100` it will check `$A1>1` in row 2, `$A2>1` in row 3, `$A3>1` in row 4 and so on. Then the wrong rows will be formatted. So for applying to `$A$2:$F$100` it must be `=($A2>1)`.

Comment: Yes, i'm usually curious, so i  tested `$A2>1` too when you added the images to your answer and i found out that it move the base of calculations one row lower for all rows in the range and your recent comment make it clear more. Thank you very much Axel ;)

Comment: See my supplement.

Comment: Like, So this code: `=AND(INDEX($A:$A,ROW())>1,ROW()>1)` is safer that `=AND($A1>1,ROW()>1)`

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. I like this solution more than the other one that is currently higher voted, because I prefer to have everything in *one* rule if possible.

Answer (score 21):

Just add an extra formula rule to the row(s) you would like to exclude.
Set the formula to `TRUE` and tick the *Stop If True* option.
This rule should be on top of the rule list.

[image: Exclude from conditional formatting]

Comment: Yes, this!  A thousand times yes!  We all have Header Rows we would like to exclude and allow our Column-Range Selects to apply for the entire Column.  This is so we may reuse the spreadsheet and paste in data of varying lengths in Rows.  This works without having to constantly re-edit the Formatting Range (a.k.a. "Applies to") and is a one-time set-it-and-forget-it Rule on your worksheet for any and all Formulas you apply to all your Columns.